# Spring Batch Admin UI - Override file upload location

Tags: java, spring

Files uploaded by the Spring Batch Admin UI are saved to the temp folder by default. How can I override the default upload file location?

Comment: Are you able to solve it? Are you using [this version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin-samples/tree/master/spring-batch-admin-angularjs) of UI?

Answer (score 1):

In **file-context.xml** , this below bean is defined

```
<bean id="fileService" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.service.LocalFileService"
            xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <property name="fileSender" ref="fileSender" />
        <property name="outputDir" value="${batch.files.upload-dir:#{systemProperties['java.io.tmpdir']}}"/>
    </bean>
```

so you need to provide property , `batch.files.upload-dir` in properties file.

e.g. I have DB2 database so when I specify this property in `batch-db2.properties`, file upload stops working with user temp directory and starts using directory specified.

Comment: Great, but we ended up reading the file from S3 in a separated step. Thanks